# How to set schedule and merge file in Anypoint Studio(MuleSoft)

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule4

I would like to set time schedule and merge file by using MuleSoft Anypoint Studio.

Example:
The file name ***(folder name)input/a.txt*** includes

```
1, 2, 3
```

and the other file name is ***(folder name)output/b.txt*** which includes

```
4, 5, 6
```

and I would like to merge ***contents of a.txt*** file into ***b.txt*** **at next day of 0AM** file like below:

***b.txt***

```
4, 5, 6
1, 2, 3
```

I think to work out this problem just using Schedule/Write function but I couldn't.

Can anyone please help to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct that using the [Scheduler](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/scheduler-concept) component, and the [File connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/file-connector/1.3/)'s [read](https://docs.mulesoft.com/file-connector/1.3/file-read) and [write](https://docs.mulesoft.com/file-connector/1.3/file-write) operations you can achieve that. I wrote an example below. For the output file you have to set the [write mode](https://docs.mulesoft.com/file-connector/1.3/file-write#write-to-existing-files) to `APPEND`, so the existing contents are not overwritten. Note that for this to work the input files need to have an end of line at the end of the record.

Note that Anypoint Studio is an IDE. It will not implement anything, however you can use it to develop a Mule application that will implement your requirements. The application will be executed by Mule Runtime, inside Studio or in some other environment.

```
<file:config name="File_Config" doc:name="File Config" />
<flow name="test-file-appendFlow" >
    <scheduler doc:name="Scheduler" >
        <scheduling-strategy >
            <fixed-frequency frequency="1" timeUnit="DAYS"/>
        </scheduling-strategy>
    </scheduler>
    <file:read doc:name="Read" config-ref="File_Config" path="/tmp/input/a.txt"/>
    <file:write doc:name="Write" config-ref="File_Config" path="/tmp/output/b.txt" mode="APPEND"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Hi, aled.
Thanks, it works.
By the way, how can I make  '4' '5' '6' start to a new line?

Comment: Hi @CindyJ, I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Hi aled, According to your solution, the output has been displaying '4', '5', '6''1', '2' '3'. I would like to insert a new line between 6 and 1.

Comment: oh, I see. I added a new line in the input files after the numbers to avoid that assuming it was required. If you want to add the new line in the application, you could use DataWeave to process the files as CSV data. That should add the new line automatically. Or use an expression to concatenate the new line character manually to the payload in a set-payload processor `#[payload ++ '\n']`.